# Scheduling teams to complete a percentage of work

Tags: schedule

I'm trying to work out how to allocate work to different teams, and my brain is struggling with the logic.

I have three different teams who arrive in a geographic area at different dates. There's a set number of jobs in the area, and each team has a set productivity (the number of jobs they can complete per day). I'm trying to work out what percentage of the jobs each team needs to complete in order for all of the jobs to be completed, and for the teams to leave the area on (roughly, give or take 1 or 2) the same date.

Some sample:

Area A has a total of 3,030 jobs which need to be completed.

Team 1 arrives in Area A on 2014-09-30 and has a productivity of 33.25 jobs/day (fractions of a job are okay!).
Team 2 arrives on 2014-10-10 and has a productivity of 28.5
Team 3 arrives on 2014-10-23 and has a productivity of 42.75

By pure trial and error I've worked out that if each team does the following % of work, they'll all finish up on 2014-11-21 and all the jobs will be completed:

Team 1: 42% of the jobs
Team 2: 28%
Team 3: 30%

Does anyone have any clues on a formula for calculating these percentages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's easy.

First off all, let's find out when all jobs will be done:

```
                       It's timeline
09.30       10.10          10.23           end of works
  |-----------|--------------|------------------|
  |   11 days |     14 days  |      X days      |
  |Team 1 work|              |                  |
  |                          |                  |
  |      Team 1 and Team 2   |                  |
  |        work together     |                  |
  |                                             |
  |        All three Teams work together        |
```

So, let's find "X":

(11+14+X) * 33,25 - all jobs, that Team 1 will do.

(14+X) * 28,5 - all jobs, that Team 2 will do.

X * 33,25 - all jobs, that Team 3 will do.

3030 - all jobs, that all three teams will do

**(11+14+X) * 33,25 + (14+X) * 28,5 + X * 33,25 = 3030**

After solving the equation:

**X ~ 17.22**

Substitute the X in the original data:

(11+14+17.22) * 33,25 = 1403,815 - all jobs, that Team 1 will do.

(14+17.22) * 28,5 = 889,77 - all jobs, that Team 2 will do.

17.22 * 33,25 = 736,155 - all jobs, that Team 3 will do.

To find done work in percentages, we should divide work of team by all amount of work, and then multiply the results by 100:

**(1403,815/3030) * 100 ~ 46% - all jobs, that Team 1 will do.**

**(889,77/3030) * 100 ~ 30% - all jobs, that Team 2 will do.**

**(736,155/3030) * 100 ~ 24% - all jobs, that Team 3 will do.**

---

P.S.

Of course:

(1403,815/3030) * 100 ~ 46,3%

(889,77/3030) * 100 ~ 29.3%

(736,155/3030) * 100 ~ 24,2%

And sum of these works isn't exactly equal to 100 percent. It happened, because we lost accuracy due to the approximation X in our calculations.